# How to get the data from the database(GOOGLE SQL CLOUD) through GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdbc, google-cloud-sql

I'm working with google app engine and I got a problem with the database.

The application is running smoothly immediately after deploying the project into the google app engine.

But after sometime when I try to run the application by giving the data in the fields, I'm getting an error message that "The username or password you entered is incorrect".

With this I understood that the server is not able to get the data from the database.

So any help in finding the solution for this problem would be appreciated. 
Thank you all.

Comment: Fix your title, it doesn't say anything about what your question is about. Add paragraphs (air) to your question, it's hard to read. Post relevant code. Re-read your question and ask yourself: would anyone else understand what I'm asking?

Comment: Ofcrse you are right, actually I wrote a question like: "How to overcome the problem in getting the data from the database through google app engine". But forum is saying that "these words are not allowed in titles". So simply I went for this title. I dont have much experience asking question in forum.

Comment: And I hope I provided some meaningful information atleast and it is enough to understand the problem for those who worked with GAE and Google SQL cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Where does the error message come from? Do you have a stack trace? Are you able to connect to you Cloud SQL instance via the command line tool? (https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/commandline)

Comment: The error message is coming at the time of submitting the log-in page of the details username and password. As I'm new to this gae app I didn't get the remaining questions of your's.

Comment: From my stack trace I found that the problem for the error is with the database connectivity.